# AC_PATH_PROG always return /usr/bin/prog instead of /my/own/path/prog

Tags: autotools, automake

My configure.ac file is checking for the Rscript program that may have one or multiple locations in different system.

```
AC_PATH_PROG([RSCRIPT], [Rscript], [na])
```

The RSCRIPT is set to /usr/local/bin/Rscript which is the same value returned from

```
which Rscript
/usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

On one of my computers. On another computer Rscript stay in two locations

```
/usr/bin/Rscript  # this one is older
which Rscript
/global/software/bin/Rscript # this one is what I wanted

PATH=/global/software/bin:/usr/bin:muchlonger/notshown
```

My PATH variable has the /global/software/bin before /usr/bin.  According to the document, AC_PATH_PROG should return the /global one rather than the /usr/bin one.  Not sure how to avoid this problem.

One hack is to set RSCRIPT variable outside configure. I am currently using this method.

Updated:

```
I constructed a minimal configure.ac file
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([minimaltest], [1.0.0], [blabal@yahoo.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Wportability])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/helloworld.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PATH_PROG([RSCRIPT], [Rscript], [na])
if test "$RSCRIPT" = na; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([Rscript binary not found on this machine!])
else
   AC_MSG_RESULT([Rscrpt path: $RSCRIPT])
fi


# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

# Checks for library functions.
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Then running configure on the "suspicious" system and get expected behavior. This is a section of the configure output:

```
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for Rscript... /global/software/r/3.5.0/bin/Rscript
Rscrpt path: /global/software/r/3.5.0/bin/Rscript
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
```

So somehow, my original configure.ac certainly has something wrong.  I will figure it out.  Thanks John for point this out.  The minimal configure.ac file is a very good idea for debugging.

Comment: We would need to review a representative [mcve] to advise you about why your `configure` script is behaving differently than you expect.

Comment: It is possible the some other part of the configure.ac or Makefile.am doing something strange or could be the funky OS: Centos. I will try to make a minimal one; it may function normally. I will let you know how my minimal behaves.

Comment: I constructed a minimal test case showing that the behavior is as expected.

Comment: One lesson learned is that I initially put AC_PATH_PROG near the end of the configure.ac file, before it I have a lots of check, conditional, .... When I move AC_PATH_PROG towards the top of the file, this fixed the problem. The action of the other MACROS might have altered the PATH variable.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved your issue.  Ideally, it would not matter where you put the `AC_PATH_PROG`, as other macros should not make permanent modifications to the path.  As you discovered, however, some macros, especially third-party ones, are not as well behaved as others.  An alternative to moving `AC_PATH_PROG` itself would be to capture the original path early `configure.ac` (i.e. store a copy in another variable), and then restore it just before `AC_PATH_PROG`.  You don't really need that here, but that kind of trick is broadly useful in Autoconf.